# In PaperTrail gem, an object's data isn't accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, paper-trail-gem

I'm using the paper_trail (https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) gem in my application for store versioning. I customize with class_name. I able to collect record through query but how to access object's data

```
ElementVersion(id: integer, item_type: string, item_id: integer, event: string, whodunnit: string, object: text, created_at: datetime)

 The object have a information are
 ---
 id: 431
 heading: some text
 body: "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html><body>\ndfklsjdalfjlds</body></html>\n"
 element_type_id: 5
 parent_id: 430
 position: 1
 version_id: 
 created_at: 2016-04-18 04:35:52.916000000 Z
 updated_at: 2016-05-13 04:56:51.371376000 Z
 ended_at: 
 lock_version: 85
 display_heading: false
 lock_time: 2016-05-13 04:56:51.000000000 Z
 locked_by: 16
 project_id: 
 survey_id: 
 cover_image_id: 
 details: "{}"
 work_id: 


ElementVersion.where_object(parent_id: 430)
```

It is returning an array of records, but I am not able to access "body" content from the above query. Do you have any ideas about how to fix this issue?

Comment: What happens when you try to access the `body`? Exception? Returns `nil`? How do you access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ElementVersion.where_object(parent_id: 430)
> It is returning an array of records, but I am not able to access "body" ..

The `Version.where_object` method returns a `Relation` of `Version` objects, just like the normal `where` method.

The [Basic Usage](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#1c-basic-usage) section of the documentation describes how to retrieve the original record from a `Version` record.

```
widget = Widget.find 153
widget.name                                 # 'Doobly'
widget.update_attributes :name => 'Wotsit'
widget.versions.last.reify.name             # 'Doobly'
```

So, you can `reify` your `ElementVersion` record to get, presumably, an `Element`, and then call `#body` on it.